# Dimensions of Javafx text before rendering

Tags: fonts, javafx-8

I create a rectangle containing text and the size of the rectangle is determined by the dimensions of the text. I use the following to get the width:

```
    Text text = new Text(myName);
    text.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 14));
    double width = text.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
```

I do this before I render anything. It gives the wrong size but after rendering,  subsequent calls to the same code block give the correct size. Unfortunately, I need it before rendering.

I assume there is some initial state that I need to get pass. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getBoundsInLocal()` instead:

```
double width = text.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
```

Comment: Could you say why?  ([Here's](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#boundsInLocalProperty) documentation for the `boundsInLocal` and `layoutBounds` properties, but I could use more explanation of why the latter doesn't work before rendering.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.